# About non-reversible Metropolis Hastings Markov chain

Tags: pr.probability, st.statistics, markov-chains

I am reading a [paper](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/s11222-015-9598-x.pdf) about constructing a non-reversible Metropolis Hastings Markov chain from a reversible one as described at a high level in paragraph $3$ of page $1$.

> But I don't understand how, given a reversible Markov chain $P$ with stationary distribution $\pi$, a non-reversible Markov chain is constructed with the same stationary distribution. This is explained in Section $2.3$.

It says the idea is, given a non-reversible Markov chain $P$ with stationary distribution $\pi$, to consider the vorticity matrix $\Gamma$ of $P$ defined (in equation $(1)$) as:

$$\Gamma(x,y):=\pi(x)P(x,y)-\pi(y)P(y,x)$$

In Section $2.3$, it says consider a Markov chain $Q$ and a vorticity matrix $\Gamma$, then it defines the non-reversible Hastings ratio as

$$R_{\Gamma}(x,y):=\begin{cases} 
\frac{\Gamma(x,y)+\pi(y)Q(y,x)}{\pi(x)Q(x,y)}\quad\text{if}\quad \pi(x)Q(x,y)\neq 0 \\
1 \quad\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$

and the acceptance probabilities as $A_\Gamma(x,y) = \min\left(1,R_\Gamma(x,y) \right)$
and finally the transition probabilities $P_{\Gamma}$ of the non-reversible Metropolis Hastings in $(9)$. Let me breakdown my misunderstanding in two questions.

> $(1)$ Firstly, is $\Gamma$ the vorticity matrix of $Q$ as it is defined in Section $2.3$?

I think it is because the inequality under $(8)$ says $\Gamma(x,y)\leq \pi(x)Q(x,y)$ which would be true only if $\Gamma$ is the vorticity matrix of $Q$ because if $\Gamma(x,y):=\pi(x)P(x,y)-\pi(y)P(y,x)$, then $\Gamma(x,y)\leq \pi(x)Q(x,y)$.

> $(2)$ If the answer to $(1)$ is yes, then how are we constructing a non-reversible Markov chain from a reversible one? Because $\Gamma\neq 0$ iff $Q$ is non-reversible and thus we are constructing a non-reversible chain $P_{\Gamma}$ from a non-reversible chain $Q$. Isn't that correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As defined after lemma 2.1, any skew-symmetric matrix $\Gamma$ (i.e. $\Gamma=-\Gamma^T$) that satisfies $\Gamma {\mathbb 1}=0$ is called a vorticity matrix. It need not be of the form $\pi(x)P(xy)-\pi(y)P(y,x)$.

Comment: Hello Dr. Peres! If I may ask a followup, are you aware of any examples of this method in speeding up mixing? I know about chains of the form $\Pi P$ which are non-reversible ($\Pi$ being a permutation matrix of the state space) and that with high probability, $\Pi P$ chains have $\log n$ mixing time.

Comment: Are you aware of Boyd, Stephen, Persi Diaconis, and Lin Xiao. "Fastest mixing Markov chain on a graph." SIAM review 46, no. 4 (2004): 667-689. https://epubs.siam.org/doi/pdf/10.1137/S0036144503423264?casa_token=Kcoivoy94a8AAAAA:FfWgcx_UfDxreLFeEQ22DTzgisVGAOziKNWQTcBy0bVGRa_jF4C0BqVe9MoK0KUnqjTnMxQqeNY

Comment: Thanks, yes, I am. In my understanding, it is analyzing the transition probabilities for which the gap is maximized. But the fastest mixing reversible chain could mix slower than a non-reversible chain with the same stationary distribution on the same state space, right?

Comment: Yes, The Cesaro mixing time of a biased walk on an n-cycle is $O(n)$ while reversible chains on that graph mix in time of order $n^2$.

Comment: Also, here is a paper about a non-reversible chain on a hypercube mixing in $O(n)$ with cutoff as opposed to a reversible chain mixing in $O(n\log n)$. https://arxiv.org/pdf/2109.05387.pdf